# WPF TextBlock shows all log messages only after all work is done

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, components, textblock

When user clicks on `Execute` button, I want to do some stuff and output log messages to `TextBlock` progressively - so user can see what is currently happening.

The problem is that my `TextBlock` changes it content after all work is finished (too late). How can I force WPF to repaint itself during process ?

Code looks like this:

```
    private void btn_execute_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        .... stuff ....
    }
```

I have tried adding `output_log.InvalidateVisual();` after any change to `TextBlock`, didn't work as expected.

Comment: Why are you doing this in the code behind? are you not using MVVM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run synchronous code in a `Click` handler of a `Button`, this code is being executed in the `Dispatcher` thread and thus prevents the `Dispatcher` from running any other code like displaying the changes of your messages in a `TextBlock`.

There are (at least) three possible ways to solve this issue.

**First**, you can run your `Execute` code in another `Thread`, `Task` or `async` event handler and set the `Text` using the `Dispatcher`:

```
private async void btn_execute_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
     {
         // Simulate doing some stuff...
         await Task.Delay(100);

         // Thanks to async/await the current context is captured and
         // switches automatically back to the Dispatcher thread after the await.
         output_log.Text += i + ", ";

         // If you were using Task.Run() instead then you would have to invoke it manually.
         // Dispatcher.Invoke(() => output_log.Text += i + ", ");
     }
}
```

The main advantage is that you are not blocking the `Dispatcher` - which is highly recommended for everything you do.

---

**Second**, you can keep doing your `Execute` code in the `Dispatcher`, but then you have to "flush" the `Dispatcher` every time when you want to refresh your text, so that it can handle all waiting UI actions:

```
private void btn_execute_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        // Simulate doing some stuff...
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        output_log.Text += i + ", ";
        Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new Action(() => { }));
    }
}
```

This is certainly possible but I really wouldn't recommend it.

---

Or **third**,

- you can use `MVVM` for your architecture,
- run your `Execute` code in an `async` event handler (or `Command`),
- change only the `LogText` property of your `ViewModel` and
- use data binding to bind the `TextBlock.Text` to this `MyLogViewModel.LogText` property.

Unfortunately I can't give you a quick sample code for this scenario, but it's surely worth thinking about it because `MVVM` is just a really natural architecture for any kind of WPF application.